# Branching ratios for alpha decay into a rotational band

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-physics, potential-energy

I want to understand the $\alpha$-decay of $242$-Curium to different excited states of $238$-Plutonium (image taken from *Introduction to Nuclear Physics* page 258; Author: Krane):

[image]

I'm interested in explaining the intensity of each $\alpha$-decay branch.

I have read from the book the following argument to justify the intensities related to the rotational bands: 'the centrifugal potential $\frac{l(l+1)\hbar^2}{2mr^2}$ raises the barrier and the excitation energy lowers it'.

Then he says: 'we obtain the following estimates using the theory of decay rates, taking into account the increasing effective binding energy and decreasing excitation energy:

\begin{align}
 0^{+}&\to 76 \% \\
2^{+} &\to 23\%\\
4^{+} &\to 1.5\% \\
6^{+} &\to 0.077\%\\
8^{+} &\to 8.4 \times 10^{-5}\%
\end{align}
**The issue is that I do not understand how can I get these estimates by the decay rate theory.**

There is another issue with the intensities; you observe these do not decrease all the time as we go up in energy (for instance: from $8^{+}$ to $1^{-}$ it goes up in intensity and not down. And this issue repeats). **Why?**

Comment: Hi PSE community, it seems my question is not catching a lot of attention... I think I ask too may questions on it. Should I edit it and focus on one issue instead? Thanks.

Comment: Greetings!  I've tried to separate your decay-rate question from your nuclear-structure question.  If you decide to re-ask the other part, you can include a link back to this one.

Comment: @rob Thank you! I will ask the second part once this question gets answered.

Comment: Outline of an answer for later: the [golden rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%27s_golden_rule) favors decays to lower-energy final states, but [the overlap integral is suppressed](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/368978/44126) if the Pu-$\alpha$ final state has to carry away angular momentum.

Comment: @rob I get that the lowest $0^{+}$ energy state is the most probable for Pu because the $\alpha$-particle has $L=0$ and the energy barrier in that state is $E = 0$. However I do not get what you mean by saying 'but the overlap integral is suppressed' (if the $\alpha$ particle carries orbital angular momentum).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On p. 253, Krane gives eq. 8.18, an estimate of the half-life of alpha decay when the angular momentum of the alpha is zero. On pp. 258-259, he discusses the reduction of the alpha decay rate when the angular momentum is not zero, due to the centrifugal barrier. I assume there is no closed-form expression for the tunneling probability in this case, so that's why he doesn't give one. Most likely he's doing numerical integration. The absolute decay rates are never going to be predicted to better than an order of magnitude, but the branching ratios only depend on one decay rate relative to another, so those come out quite close.

> There is another issue with the intensities; you observe these do not decrease all the time as we go up in energy (for instance: from 8+ to 1− it goes up in intensity and not down. And this issue repeats). Why?

The centrifugal barrier is lower.